# Duality of erosion and dilation

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to prove the duality of erosion and dilation:

$$(A \ominus B)^C=A^C \oplus \hat{B}$$

where:

\begin{align*}
\hat{B} &= \{ b \mid -b \in B \}\\
A^C &= \{ a \mid a \notin A \}\\
A \oplus B &= \{ a + b \mid a \in A, b \in B \}\\
A \ominus B &= \{ a - b \mid a \in A, b \in B \}
\end{align*}

My approach:

\begin{align*}
(A \ominus B)^C &= \{ a-b \mid a \in A, b \in B \}^C\\
&= \{ z \mid (b+z) \in A, b \in B \}^C\\
&= \{ z \mid (b+z) \notin A^C, b \in B \}^C\\
&= \{ z \mid (b+z) \in A^C \lor b \notin B \}\\
&= ???\\
&= \{ a+b \mid a \in A^C, b \in \hat{B} \}\\
&= A^C \oplus \hat{B}
\end{align*}

I've got stuck at that `???` part. Is it possible to prove it without introducing translation? I want to keep the proof simple.

Comment: This is nice. Is this theorem or you are asked to see if it is true?

Comment: It is a theorem, the usual proof is by introducing translation. I’m just wondering how to prove it without translation.

Comment: What is the universal set here? You are taking the complement.

Comment: Let A be the positive integers, B the negative. All elements of the LHS must be less than 2, the RHS contains all integers.

Comment: His formula is wrong, it should be $$(A \oplus B)^C=A^C \ominus \hat{B}$$ Take a look https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_morphology

Comment: @JohnWatson: The $\ominus$ operation in the article you link to is critically different from what the OP defines here.

Comment: @JohnWatson: But even with the definitions you link to, the two identities appear to be equivalent, by exchanging $A$ for $A^\complement$, $B$ for $\hat B$ and then complementing both sides of the equality.

Comment: For each $z$ in $\mathbb{R}$ we have $$B_z=\{b+z; b\in B\}$$  $$A\ominus B = \{z\in \mathbb{R}; B_z\subseteq A\}$$ and $$A\oplus B =\{z\in \mathbb{R}; (B^s)_z\cap A \ne \emptyset\}$$ where $$B^s = \{x\in \mathbb{R},-x\in B\}$$

Comment: Well it will take me some time to figure out what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

With the definitions you have given (and assuming everything happens in $\mathbb R$), it is not true. For example, if $A=B=\{-1,1\}$, then
$$ (A\ominus B)^\complement = \mathbb R\setminus\{-2,0,2\} $$
but
$$ A^\complement \oplus \hat B = \mathbb R$$